# MVC sorting with property on View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Say I have a view model for a list view that renders a table.

View Model:

```
  public class SortModel
  {
     public List<Document> Documents {get;set;}
     public string SortParameter {get;set;}
     public string SortOrder {get;set;}
  }

  public class Document
  {
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public int Age {get;set;}
  }
```

View:

```
   <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Documents[0].Name)</th>
   <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Documents[0].Age)</th>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(SortModel model)
{
   var docs = db.GetDocs();
   if(model.SortParameter == "Age" && model.SortOrder == "desc")
   {
      docs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Age);
   }  
   return View(model); 
}
```

How can I render the View so that the table headers are clickable and will update the model before posting? I want to avoid using ViewBag.

I'm guessing I'll need to use an ActionLink, but I'm not sure how to update the model before posting.

Something like:

```
<th>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Home", "Name", new { Model.SortParameter = "Name", Model.SortOrder = "Desc"})
```

Comment: If you are rendering all `Document` in the view, why not just sort it client side?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I didn't show it, but I'm only rendering top 100 so can't sort client side.

Comment: _"I want to avoid using ViewBag"_ - please explain this part.

Comment: You can add your table part into partial view, then with JQuery and AJAX reload your table with sorted/filtered results.

Comment: You want to search for an ajax grid. There are commercial and free products out there (Kendo UI, DataTables). Both have IQueryable Helpers.

Comment: Then probably best to use a plugin such as PagedList.Mvc. But you can always use javascript to handle the `.click()` event of the table header and make a GET to your method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you table headers to

```
<th>@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", "Home", new { SortParameter = "Name", SortOrder = Model.SortOrder }, null)</th>
<th>@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", "Home", new { SortParameter = "Age", SortOrder = Model.SortOrder }, null)</th>
```

and then modify the controller method to toggle the `SortOrder`

```
public ActionResult Index(SortModel model)
{
   var docs = db.GetDocs();
   if(model.SortParameter == "Age" && model.SortOrder == "desc")
   {
      docs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Age);
      model.SortOrder == "acs"
   }  
   return View(model); 
}
```

Note it would probably be easier if you had a `bool IsAscending` property rather than your `string SortOrder`.

However, you only have one 'SortOrder' property, so if the current view is displaying the Documents sorted by `Name` in ascending order, and the user clicks on `Age`, then the Documents will be sorted by `Age` in ascending order. If the user then clicks on `Name`, the Documents will be sorted by `Name` in descending order. You have not stated why the desired behavior is, but you could add multiple 'SortOrder' properties, say

```
public bool IsNameAscending { get; set; }
public bool IsAgeAscending { get; set; }
```

to handle that, and also to allow you to use a `.ThenBy()` in your query, for example

```
docs.OrderBy(x => x.Age).ThenBy(x=> x.Name);
```

You might also want to render a visual indicator (e.g. up or down arrows) to indicate the current sort order to the user.